# Selenium: how to change log level messages displayed in console?

Tags: java, selenium, logging

When I run my Java Selenium test, the Eclipse console displays a lot of messages like:

```
1484171436147   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1484171436149   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1484171436152   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm
1484171436154   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/PluginProvider.jsm
1484171436154   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: XPIProvider
1484171436155   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1484171436155   addons.xpi  INFO    SystemAddonInstallLocation directory is missing
1484171436156   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping aushelper@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox Developer Edition\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1484171436156   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping e10srollout@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox Developer Edition\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1484171436157   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping firefox@getpocket.com to C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox Developer Edition\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
```

I'd like to have a cleaner log. I've tried a lot of things from other questions, but nothing works. The garbage is still there.

Here is what I have now in the @BeforeClass method in my test suit:

```
LoggingPreferences loggingPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.WARNING);
loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.WARNING);
loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.WARNING);
loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.WARNING);
loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.PROFILER, Level.WARNING);
loggingPrefs.enable(LogType.SERVER, Level.WARNING);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, loggingPrefs);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```

How do I clean my log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [an answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/selenium-users/log$20level$20webdriver%7Csort:relevance/selenium-users/eDZzBg3go6o/Fpbo7_eDjz4J) at the Selenium user forums:

```
    if (driver instanceof RemoteWebDriver) {
          ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).setLogLevel(Level.WARNING);
    }
```

Using this commands just after creating the driver object solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Tried on latest version of selenium(4.16.1):

```
// create driver service first
ChromeDriverService driverService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                .withLogOutput(System.out)
                .withLogLevel(logLevel)
                .build()
// use this driver service to construct web driver
RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
```

where logLevel refers to

> org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriverLogLevel

[Consult official documentation of selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/chrome/#service)