# How to configure log level for Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, logback, slf4j

I have a project with `Selenium` and logging with `Slf4j`. I need set the log level for selenium - `INFO`. I try use `WebDriver.setLogLevel(Level.INFO)` but log anyway stay `DEBUG`.

```
WebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions());
chrome.setLogLevel(Level.INFO);
```

My `logback.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <FileNamePattern>log/log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>

             <!--keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.codingpedia" additivity="false" encoding="UTF8">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" encoding="UTF8" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

My idea is all `Trowable` write into a log file, all info about Selenium requests only into the console. But Selenium persistent using `DEBUG` level.

How to set log level `INFO` for Selenium. Thank You.

**UPDATE 1**

I fined (thanks to @Ratmir Asanov) solution, but it requires knowing key for log's `DesiredCapabilities`.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability("What key?", getCap());

DesiredCapabilities getCap() {
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.INFO);
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.PROFILER, Level.INFO);
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.INFO);
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.INFO);
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.INFO);
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.SERVER, Level.INFO);
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
    return caps;
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/klepikov/5457750#file-test-java-L28 -- Take a look here.

Comment: @Ratmir Asanov updated.

Comment: Is your question solved or you are still looking for an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium: how to change log level messages displayed in console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601401/selenium-how-to-change-log-level-messages-displayed-in-console)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code when you are creating an instance of WebDriver:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(getCap());
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: it deprecated constructor. And the second the issue this solution - I already using the constructor with ChromOptions in a parameter. I need send into ChromeDriver constructor and ChromeOptions with old preference and logging preference.

Comment: @Pavel, you can add all options like: `caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);` and then use my code in answer. Yes, it's deprecated.